# Can I install Ubuntu with full disk encryption, and then dual-boot with Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, encryption

I want to have Windows 10 and Ubuntu dual-booted in my computer and want to encrypt Ubuntu with LUKS. My question is, can i erase disk, install Ubuntu with full disk encryption and then install Windows 10 (encrypted or not).

If not, how can I install Ubuntu after Windows? I already saw some answers here but none were about 16.04.

Comment: It should be possible with two drives but not in the same considering LUKS encrypts the whole thing.

Comment: You can encrypt your home partition during install, is this what you want to do ? I don't think you need to encrypt the whole drive do you ?